# ItemManager.AddFromTemplate. How to set language used

Tags: multilingual, migration

I'm writing some code to migrate items using the `ItemManager.AddFromTemplate` method. I'm wondering how to set what language the item created from that method is created in. 
Does it default to the language set in the sites node in config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemManager.AddFromTemplate` method uses your current language.

You can wrap your code into

```c#
Language lang = Language.Parse("your-lang-name");
using (new LanguageSwitcher(lang))
{
    ItemManager.AddFromTemplate...
}
```

if you want to change the new item language.